# Detouring DrawString in dll doesn't work

Tags: c++, dll, gdi+, detours

I'm experimenting on Detours.

First of all, I have a ForHook.cpp, which uses gdiplus DrawString to print a "Hello".

```
VOID OnPaint(HDC hdc)
{
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    FontFamily  fontFamily(L"Times New Roman");
    Font        font(&fontFamily, 24, FontStyleRegular, UnitPixel);
    PointF      pointF(30.0f, 10.0f);
    SolidBrush  solidBrush(Color(255, 0, 0, 255));
    graphics.DrawString(L"Hello", -1, &font, pointF, &solidBrush);
}
```

I wrote detouring code in ForHook.cpp, it intercept DrawString command, write "Haha" to window instead of "Hello". And it works.
The code used for replace gdiplus DrawString:

```
class CDetour {
public:
    static Gdiplus::Status(CDetour::*pDrawString)(const WCHAR* s, INT len, const Gdiplus::Font *f, const Gdiplus::PointF& org, const Gdiplus::Brush* b);
    Gdiplus::Status MyDrawString(WCHAR* s, INT len, const Gdiplus::Font *f, const Gdiplus::PointF& org, const Gdiplus::Brush* b);
};
Gdiplus::Status CDetour::MyDrawString(WCHAR* s, INT len, const Gdiplus::Font *f, const Gdiplus::PointF& org, const Gdiplus::Brush* b)
{
    WCHAR* a = L"Haha!";
    return (this->*pDrawString)(a, len, f, org, b);
}

Gdiplus::Status(CDetour::* CDetour::pDrawString)(const WCHAR* s, INT len, const Gdiplus::Font *f, const Gdiplus::PointF& org, const Gdiplus::Brush* b) = (Gdiplus::Status(CDetour::*)(const WCHAR* s, INT len, const Gdiplus::Font *f, const Gdiplus::PointF& org, const Gdiplus::Brush* b))&Graphics::DrawString;
```

The detouring code:

```
Gdiplus::Status(CDetour::* pMyDrawString)(WCHAR* s, INT len, const Gdiplus::Font *f, const Gdiplus::PointF& org, const Gdiplus::Brush* b) = &CDetour::MyDrawString;
DetourTransactionBegin();
DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)(CDetour::pDrawString), *(PBYTE*)&pMyDrawString);
DetourTransactionCommit();
```

Then, I move them to dll, and load dll in ForHook.cpp.
At where I used to detouring code:

```
LoadLibrary(TEXT("Mydll.dll"));
```

The detouring code is put under DllMain:

```
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    //detours
    MessageBox(0, L"Process Attach", L"Info", MB_OK);
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)(CDetour::pDrawString), *(PBYTE*)&pMyDrawString);
    if (DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR)
    { 

        //WCHAR buffer[15];
        //_ultow_s(GetCurrentThreadId(), buffer, 15, 10);
        MessageBox(0, L"Dll successfully injected.", L"Info", MB_OK);
        //MessageBox(0, buffer, L"Info", MB_OK);
    }
    break;
```

And I use detourdetach when dll detached:

```
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    MessageBox(0, L"Process Detach", L"Info", MB_OK);
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)(CDetour::pDrawString), *(PBYTE*)&pMyDrawString);
    DetourTransactionCommit();
    break;
```

As detours API will not be called in ForHook.cpp, I also removed `#include <detours.h>` and `#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib)`.

Tricky thing is that, the dll is attached, I verified it by using Listdlls.exe. The dll is under the ForHook.exe process id. But the program still prints "Hello" instead of "Haha".

Why it doesn't work? And how could I change that?

dllmain.cpp:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <detours.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"detours.lib")

//class __declspec(dllexport) CDetour
class CDetour
{

public:
    static Gdiplus::Status(CDetour::*pDrawString)(const WCHAR* s, INT len, const Gdiplus::Font *f, const Gdiplus::PointF& org, const Gdiplus::Brush* b);
    Gdiplus::Status  MyDrawString(WCHAR* s, INT len, const Gdiplus::Font *f, const Gdiplus::PointF& org, const Gdiplus::Brush* b);

};

Gdiplus::Status CDetour::MyDrawString(WCHAR* s, INT len, const Gdiplus::Font *f, const Gdiplus::PointF& org, const Gdiplus::Brush* b)
{
    WCHAR* a = L"Haha!";
    return (this->*pDrawString)(a, len, f, org, b);
}

DWORD GetMainThreadId(DWORD dwPid)
{
    LPVOID lpTid;

    _asm
    {
        mov eax, fs:[18h]
            add eax, 36
            mov[lpTid], eax
    }

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, dwPid);
    if (hProcess == NULL)
        return NULL;

    DWORD dwTid;
    if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpTid, &dwTid, sizeof(dwTid), NULL) == FALSE)
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return NULL;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return dwTid;
}

Gdiplus::Status(CDetour::* CDetour::pDrawString)(const WCHAR* s, INT len, const Gdiplus::Font *f, const Gdiplus::PointF& org, const Gdiplus::Brush* b) = (Gdiplus::Status(CDetour::*)(const WCHAR* s, INT len, const Gdiplus::Font *f, const Gdiplus::PointF& org, const Gdiplus::Brush* b))&Graphics::DrawString;


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
    //MessageBox(0, TEXT("Why?"), TEXT("Info"), MB_OK);

    Gdiplus::Status(CDetour:: *pMyDrawString)(WCHAR* s, INT len, const Gdiplus::Font *f, const Gdiplus::PointF& org, const Gdiplus::Brush* b) = &CDetour::MyDrawString;
    //WCHAR buf[15];
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        //MessageBox(0, L"Process Attach", L"Info", MB_OK);
        //_ultow_s(GetMainThreadId(GetCurrentProcessId()), buf, 15, 10);
        //MessageBox(0, buf, L"Info", MB_OK);
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)(CDetour::pDrawString), *(PBYTE*)&pMyDrawString);
        if (DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR)
        {

            WCHAR buffer[15];
            _ultow_s(GetCurrentThreadId(), buffer, 15, 10);
            //MessageBox(0, L"Dll successfully injected.", L"Info", MB_OK);
            MessageBox(0, buffer, L"Info", MB_OK);
        }
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        //detours
        //MessageBox(0, L"Thread Attach", L"Info", MB_OK);
        //_ultow_s(GetMainThreadId(GetCurrentProcessId()), buf, 15, 10);
        //MessageBox(0, buf, L"Info", MB_OK);
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)(CDetour::pDrawString), *(PBYTE*)&pMyDrawString);
        if (DetourTransactionCommit() == NO_ERROR)
        {

            WCHAR buffer[15];
            _ultow_s(GetCurrentThreadId(), buffer, 15, 10);
            //MessageBox(0, L"Dll successfully injected.", L"Info", MB_OK);
            MessageBox(0, buffer, L"Info", MB_OK);
        }
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        //MessageBox(0, L"Thread Detach", L"Info", MB_OK);
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)(CDetour::pDrawString), *(PBYTE*)&pMyDrawString);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        //MessageBox(0, L"Proccess Detach", L"Info", MB_OK);
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)(CDetour::pDrawString), *(PBYTE*)&pMyDrawString);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first off, you want to try to avoid doing ANYTHING in DllMain().  Second, you are setting this up in PROCESS attach, when you probably actually want to call it in DLL_THREAD_ATTACH.  If you put some sort of visual markers in your code, you'll find that Windows does some *WHACKY* stuff when loading DLL's.  You will see a ProcessAttach, (Ok, Sure...), Then you'll see a ThreadAttach()... OK... But then you'll see like a ThreadDetatch(), and when your application CLOSES, you'll get a PROCESS_DETATCH, but NOT a THREAD_DETATCH...

It is VERY likely that the Thread information you are setting up in PROCESS_ATTACH is *NOT* the thread that is actually doing the WORK...  Move your code to THREAD_ATTACH, and it will probably work.  The code most likely uses TLS, another scary technology, as far as DLL's go...

Comment: I thought it might not be the same thread also. So you could see that in my DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, I tried to output current thread id. And I also let put the same code just after load dll in ForHook.cpp. The thread IDs are the same.

Comment: I took your advice, moved the code to DLL_THREAD_ATTACH, it didn't work.

Comment: Also, DLL_THREAD_ATTACH attach the dll to all threads except the process's main thread. But as right now, my OnPaint() in ForHook.cpp runs in main thread, the DLL_THREAD_ATTACH should not work.

Comment: Wait a minute, where is your CDetour class declared?  I'm thinking that the static Gdiplus::Status declaration might have something to do with this?  It could be getting declared long before the DLL is loaded, and hooked, and by this time, it's too late, and pointing at the wrong thing, or is NULL?  I'd have to see more code.  BTW, What kind of DLL are you putting this in?  If you are using an MFC dll, they are infinitely more tricky and complicated to modify the attach points.

Comment: The CDetour class is declared in dllmain.cpp. It's DLL using standard windows library.

Comment: Ian, is this enough of the code that I can compile it and try it myself?  Unless you are running Windows 2000, I think you are going to need to remove the "break;" statement from the PROCESS_ATTACH, perform the code to Detour the call only once, under THREAD_ATTACH.  What this will do, is allow the PROCESSS attach to "fall into" the THREAD attach code, and create your Detour, while allowing any OTHER thread created to also create PROPER Detours.  Make sense?  Again, I haven't compiled this, so this isn't a definitive answer, however it is what *I* would do...

Comment: Hi, Larry, I think it should have something to do with hooking a "DLL" method. I tried to hooking a normal method, like "Sleep", and it works fine. So I wondering the there is some dll load tricky I'm not aware.

Comment: I'm sure there is, when you get into x86/x64 etc.  Maybe this would be easier if you could place your entire project, (or the sample at least, I don't need (or want) the ENTIRE project--just enough to demonstrate the problem), and I could build it, and debug it, rather than make guesses.  If you want, we could get in contact off-site, until we get this figured out, then we'll post a nice answer for anyone else who's having a problem like this, then we can close this question.  Sound good?  Do you have an FTP site, or a web site you can put the zipped files on?

Comment: Larry. I've uploaded my projects. Please help checking when you have time. Thank you for your kindness and dedicating of your time.

Comment: I do more debug on the code, seems that the gdiplus has been load for 2 times, as the addresses for the same function in ForHook and Dllmain are different. I also learned from book that the dll should be load once in a process. Seems that conflicted. Is that something I understanding run.

Comment: As I mentioned, there is a "bug" in Windows that causes DLL's to be loaded twice, etc, when there is a PROCESS_ATTACH, and a THREAD_ATTACH.  When I discovered this in 2007, the debate at Microsoft was that it was the CRT guys' fault, and the CRT guys claimed it was the NTLDR guys' fault.  I never got any closure on this.  At first glance, you should see about mapping your functions outside of DllMain...  I just got laid off of my job, so I'll find some time to look at your project, and see what I can learn...